# no ejecuta bien el do......... ni el cout << "Fin de instrucción while"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual, game

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Espara crear un juego pero no funciona e do  ni
cout << "Fin de instrucción while"  que deberia hacer para que funcione

Comment: Tu codigo tiene que estar dentro de una funcion. Colocalo en `main` o en alguna otra y la llamas desde main.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour].

Answer (score 1):

Si vas a utilizar "cout" y "endl", debes importar "iostream".

Luego, encapsula tu código en la función "main" para que se pueda ejecutar.

Luego estableces el namespace "std" en el que vas a trabajar.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int z = 55;

using namespace std;

int main(){
    do {
        x = y * 15;
        cout << x << endl;
        y++;
    } while (x < z);

    cout << "Fin de la instrucción while";
    return 0;
}
```

Si no deseas fijar el namespace, deberás añadírselo a los métodos:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int z = 55;

int main(){
    do {
        x = y * 15;
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
        y++;
    } while (x < z);

    std::cout << "Fin de la instrucción while";
    return 0;
}
```